# Which datastore to use when you have unbounded(dynamic) number of fields/attributes for an entity?

Tags: java, mysql, database, elasticsearch

I am designing a system where I have a fixed set of attributes (an entity) and then some dynamic attributes per client.
e.g. customer_name, customer_id etc are common attributes.
whereas order_id, patient_number, date_of_joining etc are dynamic attributes.

I read about [EVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) being an anti-pattern. I wish to use a combination of mysql and a nosql datastore for complex queries. I already use elastic search.

I cannot let the mapping explode with unlimited number of fields. So I have devised the following model:

mysql :

```
customer, custom_attribute, custom_attribute_mapping, custom_attribute_value
```

array of nested documents in elasticsearch :

```
[{
    "field_id" :123,
    "field_type" : "date",
    "value" : "01/01/2020" // mapping type date - referred from mysql table at time on inserting data
}...]
```

I cannot use flattened mappings on es, as I wish to use range queries as well on custom fields.
Is there a better way to do it? Or an obvious choice of another database that I am too naive to see?

If I need to modify the question to add more info, I'd welcome the feedback.

P.S. : I will have large data (order in 10s of millions of records)

Comment: How are `order_id`, `patient_number` and `date_of_joining` supposed to be dynamic attributes if you are able to list them up front that easily. What do you understand by "dynamic attribute"? Sounds like `patient_number` is a normal attribute of a patient entity, but if you're designing with some sort of single "human" entity, where all the other fields are "dynamic" based on whether they're doctors or patients, I'm sure you could come up with a strange design like that.

Comment: these were examples. there could be any number of such fields. Imagine taking customer data from different clients, each having some exclusive attributes. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: So what do you do with the data? That will affect the choice of the datastore most. Whether you're doing map/reduce operations on large datasets or OLTP on specific data would give you a push one way or the other. If you're only worried about dynamic attributes, then for example Postgres with HStore or `jsonb` column might be a good solution.

Comment: main challenge is apply filters on data based on dynamic fields. filters will involve multiple fields, with a combination of match queries and range queries.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using something like [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) as a pure NoSQL database.
Or as non-popular solution, I would recommend triple stores such as [virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) or any other similar ones. Then you can use SPARQL as a query language over them and there are many drivers for such stores, e.g. [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) for Java.

Triples stores allow you to store data in the format of `<Subject predicate object>`
wherein your case subject is the customer id,  predicates are the attributes and object will be the value. All standard and dynamic attributes will be in the same table.

Triple stores can be modeled as 3 columns table in any database management system.

Comment: will check out mongo db for this use case. however, elastic search is in use already, replacing that would be a big task to say the least.

Comment: If you would like to keep elastic search and you want to keep the mapping to a minimum, then simulate triple store by having three fields subject, predicate, objects. Yet, this model will not be joint-friendly with Ellasticsearch.